# Why are the PartialView models null in a PostBack to an Asp.Net Core Razor main page view's controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have an Asp.Net Core Razor page that contains several partial views.
On the post back to the main page controller, I am getting nulls for my partial view models.

How do I ensure that these getting correctly populated and sent as part of the main view model
to my controller?

Below is a simplified example.
**Here are my model definitions:**

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }
    public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
    public string ViewName { get; set; }
    public PartialSampleViewModel PartialSampleModel { get; set; }

}

public class PartialSampleViewModel
{
    public DateTime DetailsDate { get; set; }
    public String DetailsDescription { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is my controller definition:**

```
public class MainPageController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var viewModel = new MainPageViewModel()
        {
            DocumentName = "Foo",
            DocumentNumber = "1",
            PartialSampleModel = new PartialSampleViewModel()
            {
                DetalsDate = DateTime.Now,
                DetailsDescription = "Description"
            }
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SaveDocument(MainPageViewModel mainPageViewModel)
    {
        // mainPageViewModel.PartialSampleModel is null.
    }
}
```

**Here is my main page definition:**

```
@model MainPageViewModel

<form method="post" action="SaveDocument" >
    <div id="InputFormPanel" class="InputFormPanel">
        <partial name="@Model.ViewName" model="@Model.PartialSampleModel" />
    </div>
        
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label asp-for="DocumentName">Document Name:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="DocumentName" />
        <span asp-validation-for="DocumentName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <label asp-for="DocumentNumber">Number:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="DocumentNumber" />
    </div>  

    <!-- A bunch more common fields on main page -->
    <div class="text-center panel-body">
        <button id="SaveButton" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary ApproveDocument" >Save Form</button>
    </div>  
</form>
```

**Here is my partial view definition:**

```
@model PartialSampleModelRecord

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label asp-for="DetailsDate">Date:: </label></td>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="DetailsDate" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label asp-for="DetailsDescription">Description:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="DetailsDescription" />
    </div>
</div>
<!-- A bunch more other fields -->
```

Does the issue lie with my model definitions or with the definition of my PartialView(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies with not using the for attribute on the partial view. I'll try to explain why.

A partial view *can* be part of a parent form, but the partial view isn't aware of the parent model.

Let's look at the code:

```cs
<partial name="@Model.ViewName" model="@Model.PartialSampleModel" />
```

What the model attribute on the partial tag does, is pass an instance of that model to the partial view.

In a form, only the inputs that have a (asp-) 'for' tag are posted when the form is submitted. In the example above, you are explicitly saying that partial view is not 'for' the parent's model, any inputs that it might contain, are ignored. You need to tell the form: Hey, this partial view is *for* our model, make sure whatever values it contains stay part of our model.

Change it like so:

```cs
<partial name="@Model.ViewName" for="PartialSampleModel" />
```

Comment: You are spot on except for a minor point. Having "for" and "model" in tag helper throws a runtime error on partialview load. Apparently you can only have "for" or "model" in your definition. Thx for getting me pointed.

Comment: Thanks @JohnB for pointing that error out. I'm glad you solved it and I've updated the post

Comment: You saved my day. Haven't found `for` in the docs. Always found `model`.